# Keycloack and Azure Active Directory with Spring boot

Tags: java, azure, redhat, keycloak

What I've done till now:

- I have installed Keycloack(8.0.1) and configured it, created realm, clients, and users.
- Configured couple of simple Spring Boot apps with Keycloack and it is working with SSO.

I am trying to achieve following.

- Keycloak should connect to Azure Active Directory and read the users from there (User Federation) and  authenticate, authorise users to use the application.

Created Active Directory B2C on Azure cloud.

I have gone through too many links and read through Keycloak official documentation but could not figured the way out.

Thanks in advance.